# Xamarin forms ScrollView leaves a large empty space abelow

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to put a Grid inside scrollview... But when I scroll down it scrolls to bottom leaving screen blank.. How can I restrict the scroll upto the content available?

Comment: Yeah, you’ve done something wrong because it shouldn’t do that. Can you shared your XAML?

Comment: Code would help!